# How do I use multiple similar queries with WP_Query on the same page?

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to use WP_Query several times on the same page. It works if I use the same parameters every time, but I need to change them each time like this:

```
    <php $query1 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'park', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'location' => 'Florida', 'park_type' => 'national park' )); 
    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (get_field('park_official_name')) { the_field('park_official_name'); } ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_field('park_type_names'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?> 

    <php $query2 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'park', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'location' => 'Pennsylvania', 'park_type' => 'local park' )); 
    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) : $query2->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (get_field('park_official_name')) { the_field('park_official_name'); } ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_field('park_type_names'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like query2 just isn't finding a match. Double check your args and make sure you have a location Pennsylvania and park_type of local park assigned to something.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with your approach, but without knowing your data it’s not possible to say if there’s anything wrong with the actual query args, but that’s where I’d start.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times you're going to use this query, but it MAY make more sense to run only one query and then do a `foreach` for the separate locations.  Also, no need for both  `wp_reset_query()` and  `wp_reset_postdata()`:   `wp_reset_query()` calls `wp_reset_postdata()` as part of the function.

Comment: You should remove `wp_reset_query` it should only ever be used to cleanup after `query_posts` calls, and that's a function you should avoid. Mark is probably right, the most likely explanation is that your query does work, but finds nothing. Because your code has no `if ( $query2->have_posts() )` check, there's nothing to tell you it found no posts. Also, that's an awful lot of opening and closing PHP tags, have you considered opening PHP tags once and closing them once and having more than one line of PHP between the `<?php` and the `?>` so it's easier to read? Then you could indent the code

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure there should be data for the second one, but I'll check again and maybe try another similar one to see if that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I abbreviated PA even though I didn't the other states. Oops.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.